# Python: Assignment to a variable not working

Tags: python

I'm new to python but not to programming. My problem may be linked to my lack of knowledge of the syntax.

I'm trying to retrieve portion of log from a log file. The log file may be still generating when I start to read it (it may have a start but no end) so I tried to loop waiting for the end. The script runs in an infinite loop and when I tried to debug it, there is an assignment that was reached but the assignment itself is not made and that made the exit condition always false.

```
try:
endMatches = ['***** Fin normale *****', '***** Fin anormale *****']
startMatches = ['*** START OF ']
endAttributes = []
startAttributes = []
stopSearch = False

while not stopSearch:
    if not Path(pathToLog).exists():
        continue
    logFile = open(pathToLog)
    jobLog = logFile.readlines()
    reversedLog = []
    lastloggedLine=[]
    
    if len(reversedLog) < len(jobLog):
        
        reversedLog = reversed(list(enumerate(jobLog)))
        for i, e in reversedLog:
            if any(x in e for x in endMatches):
                if endAttributes != [] and (endAttributes[2] < datetime.strptime(e[:15], '%Y%m%d %H%M%S')):
                    endAttributes = [i, e, datetime.strptime(e[:15], '%Y%m%d %H%M%S')]
                elif endAttributes == []:   
                    endAttributes = [i, e, datetime.strptime(e[:15], '%Y%m%d %H%M%S')]
            if any(x in e for x in startMatches):
                if startAttributes != [] and (startAttributes[2] < datetime.strptime(e[:15], '%Y%m%d %H%M%S')):
                    startAttributes = [lastloggedLine[0], lastloggedLine[1], datetime.strptime(lastloggedLine[1][:15], '%Y%m%d %H%M%S')]
                elif startAttributes == []:
                    startAttributes = [lastloggedLine[0], lastloggedLine[1], datetime.strptime(lastloggedLine[1][:15], '%Y%m%d %H%M%S')]
            if startAttributes != [] and endAttributes != [] and (launchJob == False or (launchJob == True and startAttributes[2] > jobLaunchTime)) and startAttributes[2] < endAttributes[2]:
                stopSearch = True
                break
            lastloggedLine = [i, e]
```

So I try to find the last start and end lines in the file and if they're both found, are the last ones in the file, the start line comes before the end line and the first line of the log contains execution time that happens after the start of the script, the stopsearch must get me out.

While debugging, I noticed that the script find the end line correctly and assigns it to endAttributes. The start line is correctly found too, the line

```
 startAttributes = [lastloggedLine[0], lastloggedLine[1], datetime.strptime(lastloggedLine[1][:15], '%Y%m%d %H%M%S')]
```

is reached but startAttributes remains empty after that.

Here's a screenshot of the debug after the assignment to startAttributes:

[image]

Comment: You're sure `any(x in e for x in startMatches)` is true so that the code under it is running? That would be the most obvious cause that I can see.

Comment: How do you know that the line ``startAttributes = [lastloggedLine[0], ...`` is reached and executed? How do you check that ``startAttributes`` is empty afterwards? Can you perhaps reduce your code to a [mcve]?

Comment: I added the screenshot after the assignment line is getting executed. @Carcigenicate I placed a conditional breakpoint on that line and the debugger stopped on it

Comment: To re-iterate, please provide a [mcve]. There is no point in us guessing about the behaviour and errors of code we cannot see.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi besides the portion that read the log file,the code is minimal. The error of indentation that you pointed was a conditional logging line that I removed while posting the question, I updated the code above

Comment: There is still at least one SyntaxError in that code. The code is still reading data we do not have. We still do not know where the breakpoint for the debug is.